# AccountManager::addAccountExplicitly() fails to create Account

Tags: android, accountmanager

My application fails to create the android account using AccountManager::addAccountExplicitly(). I do not understand why it is failing, neither I could see any error reported by AccountManager in logcat.

I am trying to create the account, and retrying once, if it fails. If the failure occurred twice I am raising the exception.

Still, during the failures, there is no way to figure out why addAccountExplicitly() is failing?

My application is failing to add account even after retry and after which I am raising an exception.

Here is what I am doing,

```
Account account = new Account(accountName, accountType);
String password = getPassword();

boolean accountCreated = mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);

if (!accountCreated && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
{
      // addAccountExplicitly can return false if the account already exists
      // but at this point, I would always want to create a new account. 
      // Hence, will attempt to remove and add account.

      mAccountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(account);
      accountCreated = mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);

       if (!accountCreated)
        {
              throw new IllegalStateException());
        }
   }
```

Can anyone guide me what I am missing?
I want to know what are the scenarios of addAccountExplicitly() failures. and how can I check the error info in case of failures?

Answer (score 0):

I have also raised this with Google:- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71697888